# Why mongo aggregate sum takes so long?

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a table collection of ~5 million documents. They look like the following:

```
 fr to weight
```

I have `6000` possible values for `fr` and `to`. I have created the following code to sum all the weights from all possible `fr` field to `to`, e.g.

```
1 1 sum(all documents with fr=1 to=1)
1 2 sum(all documents with fr=1 to=2)
...
```

I used `pyMongo` to write the script, while `cells` is an array of all possible `fr`/`to` fields, and `calls` is the collection I have my ~5 million documents.

```
for _from in cells: #pair up each cell with each other cell
     for _to in cells:
             s = calls.aggregate([
                      {
                              '$match':
                              {
                                      "fr": _from,
                                      "to": _to
                              }
                      },
                      {
                              '$group': {'_id': 'null', 'sum': {'$sum':'$weight'}}
                      }])
              if s['result']:
                     fr_to_sum = s['result'][0]['sum']
                     _id = entropy.insert({
                                     'to': _to,
                                     'fr': _from,
                                     'sum': fr_to_sum
                             })
```

I am using a single machine.

Would another database be better? E.g. some SQL?

**UPDATE**

The fields `fr` and `to` contain integers in the range of `1-100000`, while  `weight` is a small `float`. I try to make all possible combinations between `fr` and `to` and sum the values for these combinations, because there might be duplicate documents in the database which have `fr` and `to` the same (e.g. `fr=1 to=2 weight=0.004` and `fr=1 to=2 weight=0.01`, so in this case I would like to have in my `entropy` table `fr=1 to=2 weight=0.014`.

And just as a sample

```
 >> db.week_calls.count({'fr':10, 'to':102})
 >> 4
```

After calling `db.week_calls.getIndexes()` I got

```
    {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "db.week_calls",
    "name" : "_id_"
}
```

This seems odd, since I created and index on the whole thing with `db.calls.ensure_index([("fr",1), ("to",1)])`

Comment: Do you have an index on `fr` and `to` ? How many documents matches in the "range" you are selecting.

Comment: Yes, I've used `db.calls.ensure_index([("fr",1), ("to",1)])`. What do you mean by `range`?

Comment: How many documents are getting "matched" by adding your `fr` and `to` criteria. Your question would be probably also better explained by describing more of what you are trying to do. And is that you want totals on all the unique values of `fr` and `to` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic form of what you are trying to do, and **without** iterating is this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
           "fr" : "$fr",
           "to" : "$to",
        },
        "sum": { "$sum": "$weight" }
    }}
])
```

Now that **may** well blow up on you so you might need to do some looping and *"range"* the values as in:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
       "fr": { "$gt": 0, "$lte": 10000 },
       "to": { "$gt": 0, "$lte": 10000 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
           "_id": { 
                "fr" : "$fr",
                "to" : "$to",
           },
           "sum": { "$sum": "$weight" }
   }}
])
```

To *segment* all of those documents, and then get the next *segment*:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
       "fr": { "$gt": 10000, "$lte": 20000 },
       "to": { "$gt": 10000, "$lte": 20000 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
             "_id": { 
                  "fr" : "$fr",
                  "to" : "$to"
             },
            "sum": { "$sum": "$weight" }
    }]
])
```

Whichever solution that works out best for you.

The general point is let `$group` do the work for you and break that up into manageable chunks where the results may be too big for one fetch.

In future releases aggregate will return a cursor.

Comment: Thank you! This is cool :). Though now I've added manually the indexes and it's way faster than it was before. But I'll add your solution as well.

Comment: @Pio If doing it in one go is not possible. Then at least splitting up the ranges will not only be faster than you current code, but also cleaner to write.

Comment: @Pio Currently aggregate will return an array of all the matching (grouped) items, which is exactly how you are handling it now. The only difference is that there is more than 1 element in the response. So you will loop the results. Try it out in a shell to see the output format.

Comment: I just ran the code and the problem is that it exceeds the memory limits. So your suggestion to split up is perfectly valid.